# Send message to customer after the order has been created by administrator

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I use Drupal Commerce version 7.x-1.x. I want to Send message to customer automatically after the order has been created by administrator on page admin/commerce/orders/add. How can i done it with rules or hooks (for example mymodule_form_commerce_order_ui_order_form_alter) or other ways....

Comment: Please improve your question to explain which Rules **Event** you want to use ... I trust you know at a minimum that to use a custom rule (not a Rules Component), you must have "something" to start from (ie a Rules Event), right? Even better: include an export of the Rule you have so far in your question, even if it doesn't work yet, and describe the missing piece or remaining challenge you have to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by adding a rule to fire on order update and checking to see if the order the order status was previously `somestate` and the current state now `processing` or `completed`.

Of course, you'd have to ensure that the states you wanted match your workflow.